# I can not find where the logs of an updated ticket exists in vtiger opensource 6.5

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

I want to know the average between the ticket created and closed, so I need to know as I understand the update log of the ticket
where can I find the table of this, and I can not find trouble ticket table it's not exists !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes are log in `vtiger_modtracker_basic` and `vtiger_modtracker_detail`.

In `vtiger_modtracker_basic` you can find crmid, who made the change, when and what (the status)
Here the status values:

- 0 = updated

  - 1 = deleted
  - 2 = created
  - 3 = restored
  - 4 = linked
  - 5 = unlinked

In `vtiger_modtracker_detail` you can find which field has changed and the new and previous value.

So for your need, you should join both tables and calcuate the delay between the creation time and the date where the ticket changes its status from open to close.